# Fetch deserialized variable added at runtime using javassist

Tags: serialization, javassist, bytecode-manipulation

I want to fetch the variable(extra field) added to a serialized class at runtime.
For example

```
Class A
{
  String name;

}
```

int travId=123;

"travId" is a extra field added to Class A using javassist,before the object of class A is serialized.
While de-serializing , how can i fetch it?
I tried to fetch from readObject () and others(like parsing the deserialized object to Json format) , but my attempt was not successful.

And directly implement through the Object throws an no such field found compilation error.

Is there any way i can fetch the travId field using javassist at runtime.

Comment: You cannot add fields to already loaded classes. If you do it at loading time or even earlier, the fact that and how you did it, becomes irrelevant. The class *has* that field then, so if serializing it work, what’s the problem deserializing it? It works exactly the same way.

Comment: yes , I added a field to the class at class loading time.  and it is serialized i can clearly read the variable name in my file where the serialized Object is stored. But when i convert that to json (Using gson) , i am getting just the {"name":"name"}. I am not getting travId. But i can clearly read it in the file.

Comment: So you are also adding the field at loading time, in the deserialization environment? Can you inspect the field via Reflection?

Comment: I don't  know exactly how , but again i tried converting the object to string (using gson) from the scratch and it worked. Now i got the travId. :)

Comment: @Holger . and yes we can use javassist to get the fileds.